# Will IIS express run php in Visual Studio?

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

Will IIS express run PHP in visual studio?
If so, will you be able to debug php in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, IIS Express will run PHP applications.

Visual Studio can edit PHP files (and any other text files), but IIS Express does not add any additional integrations between PHP and Visual Studio, debugging included. You could theoretically create a project in Visual Studio of PHP files and set it to run from IIS Express, but there would be no debugging available.

The WebMatrix IDE lets you edit PHP files (and any other text files), but does not allow for debugging PHP applications.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

http://ruslany.net/2010/07/install-php-applications-with-webmatrix/

Comment: This is misleading and only answers half the question.